# Stored data by browser in PC

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage

I recently opened chrome to see what sites are saving data in my computer. 
I see three types of data stored by sites in my computer.

- Local Storage
- Session Storage
- Database Storage
- Cookies

Can anyone explain what is the local storage, database storage and session storage? Can they track me?

Comment: Just about any storage by a browser that is accessible by a website "can be" used to track you. Then there is "browser fingerprinting" which does not require any of this storage data to track you. You will be tracked to some extent if you browser the internet.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 and possibly earlier HTML versions specify a method to [store data locally](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) (as file, or database).  Cookies and session data have been around a while.

And yes, they can track you to some extent.  If they couldn't none of their free services would be free.  They sell ads based on who you are, what you like to do and what you search for.